# Applying product rule of differentiation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have been given this equation [image] in a past exam paper, in which I am solving for eigenfunctions & eigenvalues.

The product rule has been applied to this section in the solution but I cannot work out which should be 'f' and which should be 'g'.

The result is :    [image] after dividing through by [image], which I understand but how do I perform the product rule on my first equation?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write $$-\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-2x}\frac{dy}{dx})=-\frac{d}{dx}e^{-2x}\frac{dy}{dx}-e^{-2x}\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{dy}{dx})$$ and this is $$2e^{-2x}\frac{dy}{dx}-e^{-2x}\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sense, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just use $(fg)’ = f’g+fg’$ where $f = e^{-2x}$ and $g = \frac{dy}{dx}$.

$$f’ = \frac{d}{dx} e^{-2x} = -2e^{-2x}$$

$$g’ = \frac{d\frac{dy}{dx}}{dx} = \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

So, considering there is a negative sign as well, putting everything together, you get

$$-\left[-2e^{-2x}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}+e^{-2x}\cdot\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right] = 2e^{-2x}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}-e^{-2x}\cdot\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$